# MySQL JDBC DataSource for WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: mysql, jdbc, websphere, datasource, websphere-8

I am trying to setup a JDBC data source for my WebSphere App Server which I can call using JNDI in my application. All the tutorials I went through, mentions that I need to put `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` in the Implementation Class Name. But the MySQL jar (I am using version 8.0.30) does not have the class in the jar file. I placed the JAR in `C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\optionalLibraries\IBM\jdbc`

I found the class in the old MySQL jars 5.1.XX jars. Should I go ahead with the older jar without worry of compatibility or anything? Or should I change the class name to something the newer JAR provides.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MySQL 5.1 is out of any form of support, so using 8.0+ is a better choice. It looks like you should be using `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource`

Here's a list of changes from 5.1 to 8.0:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I got it to work, it was a bit of struggle. It was hard to find where to put the JDBC URL, but I got there in the end. I wish IBM had some good tutorials on this out there. But the info is a bit sketchy!